# the ability to make an array of objects of the same type

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object

Tell me whether it is possible to dynamically add objects of the same type to the array, that is, to write something like a foreach loop. An object of type Is can be added to the array

```
let t1: Is = {
    tr: "h",
    sin: 'a',
}
let t2: Is = {
    tr: "d",
    sin: 'n',
}
let t3: Is = {
    t1: "w",
    sin: 's',
}
let s1:Is[]=[t1, t2, t3];
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking exactly

Comment: do not manually register the entire array of these objects, since there are a lot of them of one type, but make a function that automatically adds objects of type Is to the s1

Comment: Whether it is possible or not is easily verifiable by pasting your code in a typescript environment like your IDE or https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/

Comment: You can add more details. Also, add expected result.

Comment: It is possible. Arrays have several methods for adding elements, like `push`, `unshift`, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Don't quite follow your question, but is that what you are after?

```
interface Is {
  tr: string;
  sin: string
}

const s1:Is[] = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  const item: Is = {
    tr: 'whatever',
    sin: 'whatever',
  };
  s1.push(item);
}
```